# You must run 1.8-pre1 on minecraft zoom mod

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

So I tried to get a zoom mod for Minecraft 1.8, so after i installed it i double clicked the file to start up the install wizard. But when I hit install, it cam up with this message:
"you must run the version 1.8-pre1 manually at least once"
I ran 1.8 on all of my profiles but it didnt work. I don't know what to do!

Comment: Not answer but use optifine, it features a zoom option.

Comment: what button do i press?

Comment: Go to 'Options' and then 'Controls', click the button next to the word 'zoom', press the key you want to be your zoom button, press 'done'. This needs optifine installed.

Comment: You probably need to edit the profile, tick the box in Version Selection that says "Enable experiment development version" and then in the Use Version drop down look for the pre-release version your looking for to download it

Comment: @SquizyProductions I posted this as an answer. Please upvote (up button) and select it as an answer (tick button) if I helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Not a total answer but I recommend using Optifine, which improves fps and adds an option for zoom.
To change or see the zoom button:

1. Open Minecraft.
2. Go to 'Options'
3. Go to 'Controls'
4. Click the button next to the word 'zoom'
5. Press the key you want to be your zoom button
6. Press 'done'

You can also enable pre-release version tick in profile editor in launcher, which will make you see 1.8-pre1.